# Calling function without use touching textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have 3 values where user can customize banner (color/image/border color) and those changes are added to textarea below (output is HTML).

So far i manage to get it working with button but problem is that with every change user has to press it (to see how it looks) and if i use something like onClick or onChange it will somehow update with previous change and not current change (this happens duo color picker as code is put in front and not on end (i think)).

```
<textarea name="html_code" class="form-control" id="html_code"rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Preview Banner" onclick="get_text();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_text() {                                     
    $("#preview").html($("#html_code").val());
     }
   </script>
```

So my question is, how could i make function start when text change in textarea without user editing something in it. (if something like that is even possible to achieve in this way). Thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: have you tried with `onchange ` event?

Comment: Yes i have but it doesn't work without doing some modifications to textarea afterward.

Comment: you want perform some action on your text area change right?

Comment: The script works but i'm guessing it can't detect text until user adds something manually to it (probably duo script which handles banner creation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, how could i make function start when text change in
>   textarea without user editing something in it.

Use `change` event on `textarea` (or `input` if user copy-paste value in it)

```
$("#html_code").on( "change input", function(){
    $("#preview").html( $(this).val() );
})
```

Comment: I have tried this before. Problem is if user select color/image it will update HTML (textarea) but preview won't appear. As soon as space or some modifications are done to textarea it will update it.

Comment: Can you share your attempt and replicate the issue which you have described? I want to see how change event is not getting triggered in such a case.

Comment: Edit: Thanks for help, i'll try to get it to work "somehow" because it looks like the problem is related to script which is generating banner. And as i notice now there is no text in textarea. Probably duo this factor the onChange function can't detect changes.

Comment: After editing few other things in banner generating plugin i got it to work :D Thanks for help!